# Dropdown elements pull to right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
<a href="#">
    Link
    <span class="pull-right">this disappeared</span>
</a>
</li>
```

I have dropdown menu, I want to have some part of link align to left and some to right, but when I pull them right, they just disappeared... and I don't know why

I am using bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

I think pull-right is a class that can be used for the entire ul not the elements within it hence why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps give your dropdown items a different class and style them like so

```
.dropdown-item {
    text-align: right;
}
```

When you use 'pull-right' bootstrap **floats** the elements to the right, don't think that's wise for dropdown items, I stand corrected.

Hope this helps

Comment: but it aligns all item, and I want only part ot item to be aligned right, not whole item

Comment: Try this in your `<li>` add the `<a href="#">
    Link
    <span class="dropdown-item">this disappeared</span>
</a>`

Comment: I solved already this problem. I used row and cols inside of "a" element